# why does the positional parameter $1 have different value?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I am a beginner of Linux, and I have been learning shell scripting, and I have some trouble understanding the positional parameter. I first typed into the terminal something like:

```
set this is a great place
```

and I run:

```
echo $1
```

it shows:

```
this
```

Then I tried something in a shell scripting file *test.sh*:

```
#!/bash/sh
echo $1
```

and I run the shell script on terminal:

```
sh test.sh
```

it shows nothing. AND, if I run:

```
sh test.sh hello
```

It would show **hello** on the screen. BUT, if I just run:

```
echo $1
```

on the terminal command line. It would still shows **this**

Why is the value of $1 different in two places?

Comment: They're really two different variables. Within the script the `$1` gets assigned the first parameter passed to the script. On the shell the `$1` can have any value the shell wants to assign it, so the set command can set the shell's `$1` to `this`

Answer (score 0):

$1 ($2 etc) are the arguments to the **current shell** (or shell script)

The set builtin replaces the current set of arguments with new ones.

```
% cat test.sh
#!/bash/sh
echo $1
set X Y Z
echo $1

# No args given, so $1 will start set to A, set will change it to X
% sh test.sh

X
# Args given, $1 will start set to A, set will change it to X
% sh test.sh A B C
A
X
```

Answer (score 0):

Pl. see if this explanation helps,

You can consider here two processes one is the current shell having a set of variables.

When you type,

```
set this is a great place
```

the current shell's variables get updated.

Now when you type

```
sh test.sh
```

it means you are now having a **separate process** with own set of variables. Now those two
set of variables are not the same. So in this case you get a different ouptput.

One very well writen  shell scripting tutorial from Apple can be found below,

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/opensource/conceptual/shellscripting/Introduction/Introduction.html